# How to make a help box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In many websites, there are help box `[?]` with a `input` which is when hovered shows up/pops up a small box of help/info . I could found it that they are made with `java script` and `jquery`. But, how ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow! No javascript nor jQuery: CSS and HTML only: http://jsfiddle.net/eckhavwq/1/ play with this and before asking the next question please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">Welcome <span class="wrapper">[?]<span class="tooltip">I am a tooltip!</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: help;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper .tooltip {
  background: #1496bb;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  left: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
} 
.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       -o-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/LpjLuL81/1/)**

Comment: Update answer with <span> inside <span>

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably could do it without any js or css, just using `span` tag and `title` attribute. I've created jsFiddle to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/nowk7cqr/1/

```
This <span title="Need some help?"> [?] </span> is a tooltip.
```

Comment: please add the code to your answer. When your link will be broken no one can see what've you done

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer.